If $f_i\in\Bbb Q[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ have no common zero in $\Bbb C$, then $(f_1,\cdots,f_m)=(1)$ in $\Bbb Q[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$
The question comes from the exercise in the textbook Algebraic Geometry by Milne:

If $f_1, \cdots ,f_m \in \mathbb{Q}\left[x_1, \cdots ,x_n \right]$ have no common zero in $\mathbb{C}$, then there exist $g_1, \cdots ,g_m \in \mathbb{Q}\left[x_1, \cdots ,x_n \right]$ such that $f_{1}g_{1} + \cdots f_m g_m =1$.

It is easy to show that 1 is contained in the radical ideal of $\sum (f_i)$ hence there exist $g_1, \cdots ,g_m \in \mathbb{C}\left[x_1, \cdots ,x_n \right]$ such that $f_{1}g_{1} + \cdots f_m g_m =1$. But I cannot show that the coefficients of $g_i$ are contained in $\mathbb{Q}$. How can I prove it? There is a hint to use 'linear algebra'.
Any idea will be helpful to me. Thanks for your help!

Shouldn’t the imaginary part just go to zero? So you can split each polynomial $f_i$.

Consider the exact sequence of $\Bbb Q$-vector spaces $$0\to (f_1,\cdots,f_m) \to \Bbb Q[x_1,\cdots,x_n] \to \Bbb Q[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/(f_1,\cdots,f_m)\to 0.$$ When we apply $-\otimes_{\Bbb Q}\Bbb C$ to this sequence, it stays exact, since $\Bbb C$ is flat as a $\Bbb Q$-vector space. So we may conclude that $$\Bbb Q[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/(f_1,\cdots,f_m) \otimes_{\Bbb Q} \Bbb C \cong \Bbb C[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/(f_1,\cdots,f_m),$$ and by assumption the RHS is a zero-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb C$. This implies that $\Bbb Q[x_1,\cdots,x_n]/(f_1,\cdots,f_m)$ is a zero-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb Q$, so $(f_1,\cdots,f_m)=\Bbb Q[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ and therefore $1\in(f_1,\cdots,f_m)$ as desired.

Thanks a lot :)

@ImBear You're welcome. If this solves your problem, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it. You can find out more about accepting answers here: How do I accept an answer?, Why should we accept answers?, What should I do if someone answers my question?.
